# Delphi XE2 VCL styles, changing window Icon doesn't update on the caption bar until RecreateWnd

Tags: delphi, styles, delphi-xe2, vcl

Another weird glitch with VCL styles:

Changing a form's Icon updates only its taskbar button, the Icon in the caption doesn't update unless you use RecreateWnd. (when using VCL styles)

```
ImageList3.GetIcon(0,Form1.Icon);
```

Is there a way to fix it without having to use RecreateWnd? (which can actually create [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009842/delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-weird-glitch-window-invisible))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's (yet another) bug in VCL styles. The `TFormStyleHook.GetIconFast` function is returning a stale icon handle. I'd fix it by replacing `TFormStyleHook.GetIconFast` with `TFormStyleHook.GetIcon`. Add this to one of your units and all is well again.

```
procedure PatchCode(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: Integer);
var
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(Address, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    Move(NewCode, Address^, Size);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, Address, Size);
    VirtualProtect(Address, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

procedure RedirectProcedure(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := NativeInt(NewAddress)-NativeInt(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  PatchCode(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

type
  TFormStyleHookHelper = class helper for TFormStyleHook
    function GetIconFastAddress: Pointer;
    function GetIconAddress: Pointer;
  end;

function TFormStyleHookHelper.GetIconFastAddress: Pointer;
var
  MethodPtr: function: TIcon of object;
begin
  MethodPtr := Self.GetIconFast;
  Result := TMethod(MethodPtr).Code;
end;

function TFormStyleHookHelper.GetIconAddress: Pointer;
var
  MethodPtr: function: TIcon of object;
begin
  MethodPtr := Self.GetIcon;
  Result := TMethod(MethodPtr).Code;
end;

initialization
  RedirectProcedure(
    Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook(nil).GetIconFastAddress,
    Vcl.Forms.TFormStyleHook(nil).GetIconAddress
  );
```

Comment: Awesome, that works perfect, tyvm. Put it all in a new unit and added it to the form where I need to change the icon, works flawlessly now.

Comment: @warren yes, I will get to that

Comment: Any way to make this work in 64-bit? The icon isn't drawn at all even on startup with a 64-bit project. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see why this does not work in 64 bit and I don't have a simple solution.